# fd-find does not find anything

Tags: fd

fd-find does not finding anything. When searching something in home directory it instantly exists without any error.

```bash
❯ mkdir root

❯ cd root

❯ touch test

❯ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 s1n7ax s1n7ax 0 Jul  6 21:29 test

❯ which fd
/home/s1n7ax/.cargo/bin/fd

❯ fd --version
fd 8.7.0

❯ fd test

❯ fd -t f test
```

I tried installing the same binary using apt package manages as well. it installs `8.3.1` version and binary name changes to fdfind yet no results

Comment: Possibly your `~/.config/fd/ignore` or `~/.gitconfig` or `~/.config/git/config` ignoring too many things?

Comment: Is it the same with `XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/dev/null HOME=/dev/null fd test`?

Comment: Oh, looks like it looks in many more conf files than that. Check with `strace -ze file fd test` to see what it finds that may have exclude patterns, that could also be in `.gitignore` files  or other in any of the ancestor directories.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas It was the .gitignore. My home directory is a repository and I'm ignoring everything that does not starts with a . (dot). So yeah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless passed the `-I` option, `fdfind` ignores the same files `git` ignores and more by looking into the same files as `git` looks into plus a few of its own.

Quoting the description of the `-I` option from [its man page on Debian](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/fd-find/fdfind.1.en.html):

> `-I`, `--no-ignore`
> Show search results from files and directories that would otherwise be ignored by
>
> - `.gitignore`
> - `.git/info/exclude`
> - The global `gitignore` configuration (by default `$HOME/.config/git/ignore`)
> - `.ignore`
> - `.fdignore`
> - The global `fd` ignore file (usually `$HOME/.config/fd/ignore`)
>
> The flag can be overridden with '--ignore'.

To see which of those conf files (and possibly more) `fdfind` finds, you can run it as:

```
strace -ze file fdfind test
```

Where  `strace` will report the successful (`-z`) file-related system calls `fdfind` makes where you might see it open a `.gitignore` file in the parent directory or parent's parent or some other file that specifies patterns of files or directories to ignore in a gitignore fashion.